# C - Root of n-ary tree not being saved/updated

Tags: c, csv, null, binary-tree, root

I am trying to write a program that represents a family tree as an n-ary tree. The program must read in names from a CSV file and build the tree. The tree is represented by the following struct:

```
typedef
   struct NTree_S {
      char * name; // name of the person
      struct NTree_S *next; // pointer to first child
      struct NTree_S *child; // pointer to next sibling 
   } NTree;
```

When using hard-coded values the program has no problem building the tree and updating the root.

```
// CASE #4 //
    printf("%s\n", "Entered CASE #4");
    NTree *root4 = NULL;
    root4 = add_child(root4, "Dad", "Son");
    root4 = add_child(root4, "Son", "Baby");
    print_tree(root4, root4->name);
```

Output:

```
Entered CASE #4
Dad had Son
Son had Baby
Baby had no offspring.
```

However, when using the build_tree() function the program does not save the root.

```
NTree * build_tree( FILE *fp) {
    NTree* root = NULL;
    char line[1024]; // max length of any line in an input file 
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(line, ",");
        char *parent = token; // save first token as parent
        while(token != NULL) {
            token = strtok(NULL, ","); // get next token
            root = add_child(root, parent, token); // add child
            if(root == NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", "root is NULL");
            }
        }
    }
    return root; // built tree 
}
```

The function gets the correct parent and token (child) to add but always prints that the tree is NULL. I am unsure as to why the root is not being saved and updated. I am hesitant to change my implementation to use a pointer to a pointer because of the working hard-coded example. Why is the root updated and saved in the hard-coded example and not in build_tree()?

**UPDATE**:

I changed the build_tree() declaration:

```
void build_tree(NTree** root, FILE *fp);
```

And I call add_child() like so:

```
add_child(root, parent, token); // add child
```

However, I am still having the same issue with the root. Every time I print the tree a segmentation fault occurs because the root is NULL. Could somebody give me feedback on my add_child function?

```
void add_child(NTree **tree, char* parent, char* child) {
        NTree *add = create_node(child); // node to add
        if(*tree == NULL) { // tree is empty
            *tree = create_node(parent); // add parent as the root 
            (*tree)->child = add;
            return;
        }
        NTree *found = find_node(*tree, parent); // search tree for parent
        if(found != NULL) { // found parent
            printf("%s\n", "found parent");
            NTree *found2 = find_node(found, child); // search parent tree 
            if(found2 == NULL) { // child not already in tree
                found =add_child_helper(found, child); // add child 
                return;
            } else {
                // error
                return;
            }
        } else { // parent not found
            int cmp = strcmp((*tree)->name, child); // child is root
            if(cmp == 0) {
                NTree *newroot = create_node(parent); // new root
                newroot->child = *tree;
                return;
            } else {
                // error 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

NTree * add_child_helper(NTree *parent, char* child) {
    if(parent->child) { // parent already has child
        return add_sibling(parent->child, child);
    } else {
        parent->child = create_node(child); // make child
        return parent;
    }
    }

NTree * add_sibling(NTree *child, char* sibling) {
    while(child->next) { // find last sibling
        child = child->next;
    }
    child->next = create_node(sibling); // add the sibling
    return child;
}
```

UPDATE 2:
    When run from the command line, the original root is being saved but the children are not being placed properly. Here's an example:

- command>add Dad, Son
- root is null...
- command>print Dad
- Dad had Son
- Son had no offspring.
- command>add Son, Baby
- found parent
- parent name: Son
- error: child is already in the tree as a child of the parent.
- command>add Random, random
- found parent
- parent name: Random
- error: child is already in the tree as a child of the parent.
- command>print Dad
- Dad had random
- random had no offspring.

The Dad root is saved but it will only have one child. Should add_child_helper use a pointer to pointer too?

Comment: `struct NTree_S *next; // pointer to first child` and 
      `struct NTree_S *child; // pointer to next sibling` ... I think you have the comments mixed up here.

Comment: You also know that you keep overwriting your `line` buffer contents, which means you'll overwrite prior parent/child names you read in, right? If you want to do it this way, you'll need to allocate a new line buffer for each `fgets` call.

Comment: I want to overwrite prior names so I can add a new child each time. I still do not understand why the root is not changing.

Comment: @NULL: You're passing the root pointer itself to `add_child()`; essentally, `add_child()` works on a copy of the root pointer. So, when it modifies its copy, the modification is only visible within the `add_child()` function. To fix, `add_child()` function must take a **pointer to the root pointer**, i.e. `void add_child(NTree **root, const char *parent, const char *child)`, so that changing the root becomes `(*root) = new_root`, which is visible in the caller too.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Any chance you could take a look at my updated add_child function?

Comment: With your new `add_child` definition, you'll need to pass the address of `root` if you want to pass the `root` pointer back through as an argument `add_child(&root, parent, token);` But that said, your original version with the `return` should have worked.

Comment: @lurker I added an example of the program run from the command line. The program gets the command and calls add_child and passes the address of root. The root is being saved but the children are not being updated. Should my helper functions use pointer to pointers too?

Comment: Anything you want to return as an argument must be done using an "address of" (`&`) in C.

Answer (score 0):

I changed both of these functions to take double pointers:

```
add_sibling(NTree** child, char* sibling);
add_child_helper(NTree** parent, char* child);
```

Passing in &root to add_child updated the root properly.

```
add_child(&root, parent, child);
```

Thank you for the help.